# Fill Skill bar on scroll limit scroll height

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll

Im doing my portfolio website and i have a question/problem.
When i scroll to the skills bars, they fill up but following the page weight and not the seccion.
There is my snippet to help you understand better the problem.
The objective is endding on skills seccion and not the end of the entire website.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("html").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 3000px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#skills {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1750px;
  height: 730px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #151721;
}

.skillstitle {
  padding-top: 90px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #6274da;
  margin-left: 140px;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 90px;
}

.container {
  margin-left: 145px;
  margin-right: 500px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 25px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.skills {
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.skillshtml {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 219px;
  left: 160px;
}

.html {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #f06529;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}

.htmlprct {
  position: absolute;
  top: 214px;
  left: 570px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="skills">
  <div id="skilltxt">
    <h1 class="skillstitle"> Skills </h1>
    <p class="skillshtml" id="skillshtml">HTML</p>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="skills html" id="html"></div>
      <p class="htmlprct">90%</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you need more code or info i can give

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us experience what you are experiencing.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier i can give you the repository if is more simple, the problem is when i scroll down the bar fill but with the "page height size, and not when you are in the right space/seccion [link](https://github.com/Gongaz/portfolio)

Comment: No, thank you. You're able to create a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) which can run your code here on this page. We're then able to copy that snippet and present you with a running answer. Links to repo's or other resources could go stale. You don't have to use everything you have, just the bare minimum to  be able to get the same behaviour you're experiencing.

Comment: let me see im new and im not good on this i will go try

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Here he is, try in full screen i think is better, thanks for make me learn more thinks about stackoverflow tools

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify: you want the meters to *start filling* whenever the section comes into view? And when should it stop filling? As an alternative, you could animate the bars to fill whenever the section enters into view.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I want it to start filling when the bar is visible and stop when the section is completely visible, here is happening by the webpage total height

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you you are calculating the width of the skill bars based on the entire height of the document, rather than the height of the section.

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction();
};

function myFunction() {
  var skillsSection = document.getElementById("skills");
  var skillsSectionTop = skillsSection.offsetTop;
  var skillsSectionHeight = skillsSection.offsetHeight;
  var winScroll = window.pageYOffset;
  var winHeight = window.innerHeight;
  var skillsFillPercentage = ((winScroll - skillsSectionTop + winHeight) / skillsSectionHeight) * 100;

  document.getElementById("html").style.width = skillsFillPercentage + "%";
  // repeat for other skill bars as needed
}
```

Comment: So i tried this one, and the bar doesnt stop to fill if i continue to scroll, possible im doing something wrong.thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to detect if the skills section is in view. This way you don't have to do any animations off screen. Whenever the element enters the view, add the scroll event listener.

Inside the event listener, calculate the distance from the bottom of the section div to the bottom of the screen with [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).By dividing the viewport height by the distance to the bottom of the view we can calculate the percentage of animation that needs to fill the bars.

```js
const skillsSection = document.getElementById('skills');
const htmlBar = document.getElementById('html-bar');
const cssBar = document.getElementById('css-bar');

function onScroll() {
  const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
  const { bottom } = skillsSection.getBoundingClientRect();
  const percentage = (viewportHeight / bottom) * 100;
  
  htmlBar.style.scale = `${percentage / 100} 1`;
  cssBar.style.scale = `${percentage / 100} 1`;
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  for (const { isIntersecting, target } of entries) {
    if (isIntersecting) {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    } else {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    }
  }
});

observer.observe(skillsSection);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 3000px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#skills {
  position: relative;
  top: 1750px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #151721;
  padding: 90px 0;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.skillstitle {
  color: #6274da;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 90px;
}

.skill {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.skill-meter {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.skill-label {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15px;
  translate: 0 -50%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.skill-percent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.skill-range {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.skill-fill {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  scale: 0 1;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: scale 0s ease;
}

#html-bar {
  background-color: #f06529;
}

#css-bar {
  background-color: #2977f0;
}
```

```html
<div id="skills">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="skillstitle"> Skills </h1>

    <div class="skill">
      <div class="skill-meter">
        <p class="skill-label">HTML</p>
        <p class="skill-percent">90%</p>
        
        <div class="skill-range" style="width: 90%;">
          <div class="skill-fill" id="html-bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="skill">
      <div class="skill-meter">
        <p class="skill-label">CSS</p>
        <p class="skill-percent">80%</p>
        
        <div class="skill-range" style="width: 80%;">
          <div class="skill-fill" id="css-bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I go try this one, thank you